# Signalr With Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am facing an issue while integrating signalr with angular, i can able to call a hub function from angular factory, but i can't push method from server to client.

```
app.factory("Signalr", function ($rootScope, $q) {
        var MyHub = $.connection.MyHub;
        $.connection.hub.url = "mydomain.com/signalr";
        var SignalR = {};
        SignalR.StratHub = function () {
            connection = $.connection.hub.start();
        },
        SignalR.CreateConnection = function (UniqueId) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            connection.done(function () {
                MyHub.server.connectNetPetDevice(UniqueId).done(function

                (ConnectionInfo) {
                    if (ConnectionInfo) {
                        defer.resolve(ConnectionInfo);
                    }
                    else {
                        defer.reject('Failed');
                    }
                })
            })
            return defer.promise;
        },
        SignalR.TestCall = function () {
            MyHub.client.testCall("Test") = function (data) {
                alert(data);
            };
        }
        return SignalR;
    });
```

In Controller

```
        app.controller("Controller", function ($scope, Signalr) {

        Signalr.StratHub();
        Signalr.CreateConnection("123456789321456").then(function (ConnectionInfo)      {
            alert(ConnectionInfo);
        })
        SignalR.TestCall().then(function (data) {
            alert(data)
        });

    })
```